# Drop down not populating dynamically in jade, node js, express js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm new to Node js. I'm trying to populate the dropdown dynamically based on a selection.

I'm doing an AJAX call and getting the response properly to jade. But the drop down is not getting populated in jade with the response data.

loc.jade

```
  label(for='unit_number') Unit Number
                            .form-group
                                select.form-control(name="unit_number", 
                                      id="unit_number",required=true)
                                    option(value='') Select Unit Number
```

AJAX

```
                   $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8082/location/getUnitNbrs',

                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                            $('#unit_number').contents().remove();
                            var newOption = $('<option/>');
                            console.log(data[j]);
                            newOption.attr('text', data[j]);
                            newOption.attr('value', data[j]);
                            console.log(newOption);
                            $('#unit_number').append(newOption);
                          }
                        }
                    });
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The first thought that occurs is that `$('#unit_number').contents().remove();` probably shouldn't be inside the loop. If moving that doesn't fix it could you post the output of the logging?

Comment: Thanks Skirtle. this worked:

        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                                console.log(data[j]);
                                $("#unit_number").append
                                                ("<option value='" + data[j] + "' >" + data[j] 
                                         + "</option>");
                            }